# "Select" query that provides differential privacy

Tags: data-privacy, differential-privacy

We possess a database containing entries, where each entry consists of a person's ID and the corresponding fractional number $w$ (e.g., 2.34, 3.4, 12.3 etc) falling within the range of 1.00 to 100.00. We are considering sending a "SELECT" query to this database, aiming to add some noise to the corresponding row (let's say by the Laplace mechanism) and return the noisy secret to the individual.

I am wondering whether such a query is permissible within the framework of differential privacy. If it is, could you please guide me on how to provide differential privacy for this query? How should $\epsilon$ be computed in the Laplace mechanism? It is essential that the output of the query does not disclose any extra information to potential adversaries.

The database is locally accessed.

Comment: I edited the question now and clarified it. There was a typo in the question. We aim to make $w$ noisy after sending the query "Select".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described, I think that it is a bad idea. I assume that a query consists of supplying an ID and the goal is to hide the associated fraction from an adversary.

However, as an adversary if I submit multiple `SELECT` queries with the same ID the process would add (presumably) independent Laplace noise to the value. By taking the mean of the returned values, I have an unbiased estimator for the value and given sufficiently many queries I can estimate the value to high precision with high confidence.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase my question: Within the context of differential privacy, we submit queries to extract information from a dataset while maintaining privacy. These queries typically involve tasks like determining counts, maximum values, medians, and so on. I'm curious about the relevance of using a "SELECT" query in this context. If it is applicable, what adjustments should be made to the epsilon and Laplace function? Perhaps, should I consider the range between the minimum and maximum values in the database as the sensitivity? In my example, the difference between the min and max of $w$.

Comment: What you describe is not a "valid" attack on differential privacy. Differential privacy is a *parameterized* notion. So if calling the mechanism once is $(\epsilon,\delta)$-DP, calling it $k$ times is something like $(\epsilon k, \delta\sqrt{k})$-DP (maybe -- I'd have to check). For large enough $k$ this will start to give vacuous guarantees (and you will be able to recover the underlying value), but the solution to that is to tune $\epsilon, \delta$, and restrict the number of queries that can occur.